# CloudFormation - Full EC2 DNS suffix by region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

AWS uses different DNS suffixes for certain regions. Most notable is us-east-1. For public IP addresses, the DNS hostname takes the form ec2-public-ipv4-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com for the us-east-1 region, and ec2-public-ipv4-address.region.compute.amazonaws.com for other regions.

This is a simple enough rule to handle conditionally, or using a Mapping, but I wondered if CloudFormation offers a pseudo-parameter or some other way of returning directly what the complete suffix ought to be for a given region.

I'm aware of the AWS::URLSuffix parameter, which for most regions returns 'amazonaws.com', but that's not quite enough by itself.

Comment: I think you may have accidentally created `route53` as a duplicate tag where `amazon-route53` already exists. Please be mindful of this in the future, thank you!

Comment: No, I didn't create that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Fn::GetAtt to get the Public DNS as mentioned in the Return Values here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-returnvalues

```
{"Fn::GetAtt":["EC2LogicalResourceName","PublicDnsName"]}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. However, that only works if I actually have an AWS::EC2::Instance resource in my CloudFormation, which I don't.

Comment: What are the resources you are trying to spin up?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I have a reference to an ElasticIP, and I am trying to create a Route53 RecordSetGroup using the expected public DNS name that would be assigned to whatever that EIP eventually gets assigned to. That assignment has not yet necessarily happened.

To be clear, this is not a problem to do with conditional logic. In fact, it's already working for me. I just would like to know if there is a method that is nicer than my current solution which involves a Condition and a Fn::If.